# Upcoming Appointments in the Inbox of Microsoft Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook

How do I turn on show upcoming appointments from my calendar in my Inbox? It currently shows No Upcoming Appointments when my Calendar is full of them. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If meetings are appearing in your Calendar without you accepting, then turn off "Automatically accept meeting requests and process cancellations"

For upcoming appointments look in the To Do bar.  http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/outlook-help/best-practices-for-outlook-2010-HA102459562.aspx#_Toc283818125